# Type expected error VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE8QU.png)Please assist, I get a "Type expected" error on my code for a windows based application. I get the error on this line "Dim objSW As New StreamWriter(objFS)"

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim strFileName As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\empout_fixed.txt"
        Dim objFS As New FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
        Dim objSW As New StreamWriter(objFS)
        Dim strEmpName As String
        Dim intDeptNbr As Integer
        Dim strJobTitle As String
        Dim dtmHireDate As Date
        Dim sngHrlyRate As Single
        strEmpName = “Thabo Lereko”
        intDeptNbr = 1001
        strJobTitle = “Junior Programmer”
        dtmHireDate = #10/05/2014#
        sngHrlyRate = 99.99
        ' Write out the record to the file ...
        objSW.WriteLine(strEmpName.PadRight(20) &
        intDeptNbr.ToString.PadLeft(4) &
        Space(5) &
        strJobTitle.PadRight(21) &
        Format(dtmHireDate, "M/d/yyyy").PadRight(10) &
        Format(sngHrlyRate, "Standard").PadLeft(5))
        MsgBox("Record was written to the output file.")
        objSW.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why did you think it was a good idea to not tell us what line the error occurs on?

Comment: I get this error on StreamWriter(objFS)

Comment: That code works, just tested it and such error should not happen on that line, the problem is due to something else we don't see in your question. Hence we can't help you. Also I like to remind you that FileStream and StreamWriter implement iDisposable, so always use using-statement with them.

Comment: empout_fixed.txt : "Thabo Lereko        1001     Junior Programmer    10/5/2014 99.99"  - Tested actually working, as Esko says

Comment: Maybe give us the EXACT exception, it's full description, stack trace, everything...  It may guide us to what's going wrong for you.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and attach the picture

Comment: I have added the image

Comment: Restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you **have named your project "StreamWriter"**, which causes "StreamWriter" to refer to the namespace of the project. Maybe you should use more a bit more descriptive project names in the future just for clarity?

You can fix this by referring to the real StreamWriter with namespace:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim strFileName As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\empout_fixed.txt"
        Using objFS As New FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
         Using objSW As New System.IO.StreamWriter(objFS)
          Dim strEmpName As String
          Dim intDeptNbr As Integer
          Dim strJobTitle As String
          Dim dtmHireDate As Date
          Dim sngHrlyRate As Single
          strEmpName = “Thabo Lereko”
          intDeptNbr = 1001
          strJobTitle = “Junior Programmer”
          dtmHireDate = #10/05/2014#
          sngHrlyRate = 99.99
          ' Write out the record to the file ...
          objSW.WriteLine(strEmpName.PadRight(20) &
          intDeptNbr.ToString.PadLeft(4) &
          Space(5) &
          strJobTitle.PadRight(21) &
          Format(dtmHireDate, "M/d/yyyy").PadRight(10) &
          Format(sngHrlyRate, "Standard").PadLeft(5))
          MsgBox("Record was written to the output file.")              
         End Using
      End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Ps. Added the using-statements that should always be used with iDisposable-objects. Removed the unnecessary close-call also.

Comment: Thank you very much Esko